# How to implement horizontal scrolling with fixed number of items?

Tags: android, xml, horizontal-scrolling

So below are the two pics. If I scroll horizontally at the top in the first picture, the top layout gets scrolled. Result is the second picture. Note that its not the continuous scroll. Either its the first or the second picture.

First Picture:

[image]

Second Picture:

[image]

I have tried HorizontalScrollView but that does not meet the proper criteria. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into the `ViewPager` widget

Comment: Sure I will try and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: ViewPager worked as a charm. Thanks a ton!!